# Dimmer Switch Installation in Multi Gang Box

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I want to install a smart dimmer switch in a 3 switch box (which requires neutral). However the one switch I need to replace is one of the simple toggle switches with 2 black wires connected inside the switch. The other 2 switches in the box have the neutral connections. The whole box is on the same circuit. Is it still possible to install this dimmer switch in this box?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: Yes I will try to post a photo tonight.